# Vue and Summernote - content from model not showing in form when loaded from db

Tags: javascript, vue.js, model, summernote

Ok, I have a form in which I am using the wysiwyg editor summernote several times. When I fill in my form, the model is updated correctly, the content is shown and the results are saved correctly to the database. **BUT** when I want to edit and load the data from the database, the model is showing the contents correctly in the developer tools, but nothing makes it on to the screen.

This is what I have:

I have a component to load and initiate the summernote editor

```
<template>
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props : {
            model: {
                required: true
            },
            height: {
                type: String,
                default: '150'
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let config = {
                height: this.height,
            };
            let vm = this;
            config.callbacks = {
                onInit: function () {
                    $(vm.$el).summernote("code", vm.model);
                },
                onChange: function () {
                    vm.$emit('update:model', $(vm.$el).summernote('code'));
                },
            };
            $(this.$el).summernote(config);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have a form (here is only one part of it) where I load the Summernote component as `html-editor`:

```
<html-editor 
   :model.sync="form.areaOfWork" 
   :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('areaOfWork') }" 
   name="areaOfWork" 
   id="areaOfWork"></html-editor>
```

In the props, after loading from the DB, the data shows correctly, i.e.:

```
model:"<p> ... my content ...</p>"
```

Likewise, in my form it shows correctly, i.e.:

```
form: Object
  areaOfWork: "<p> ... my content ...</p>"
  ...
```

But it is not shown in `html-editor`. I am stuck - maybe it is something super simple I am overlooking, but I did not find anything that helped me so far. Thanks for ideas and inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stemmed from using jquery and vue in one project!

Because vue uses virtual DOM and jquery changes the real DOM, this makes the conflict!
So it is better not to use both of them in one project or use jquery safe in it like link below:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, @soroush, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. There is a communication and it seems to work. I do see my form being filled with correct data as well.

After playing around with numerous ideas, I found a simple work-around: watcher

I added

```
      watch: {
        areaOfWork: (val) => {
          $('#areaOfWork').summernote("code", val);
        }
      },
```

to my template and the according variables to my `data()`.
When I call my database and read the item, I provide the data for the watcher and it works.

Still, I do not get why `vm.model` in the onInit callback is not shown, but as it seems to work, I wanted to provide you with an answer. Maybe it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<textarea class="summernote-editor"name="memo_content"id="memo_content"</textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('#memo_content').summernote("code", response.data.res.memo_content);
```